# android scrollview child setAlpha - Scrolling jurky

Tags: android

I am using ScrollView,

Within `ScrollView` I have `LinearLayout` with fews ImageView childs,
Now I'm facing an issue that whenever, we will doing                       `cellSeatLayout.setAlpha(0.3f)`; to scrollview Child , then ScrollView scrolling g et stcuk means smoothness is gone, and as soon as we remove Alpha by using this                         `cellSeatLayout.setAlpha(1);` now ScrollView working fine

Below is code How I using the `setAlpfa()` for refreshing my `ScrollView` childs

```
                   //check for enable/disable
                    if(data.isEnabled){
                        cellSeatLayout.setAlpha(1);
                        //cellSeatLayout.setEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        cellSeatLayout.setAlpha(0.3f);
                        //cellSeatLayout.setEnabled(false);
                    }
```

Comment: Setting alpha runs on the UI thread and hence your smoothness is gone as Scrollview is scrolled only after set alpha is completed. I wouldn't suggest toggling alpha in a scroll view.

Comment: but it will work in case of `setAlpfa(1);`, Both are executing in main thread,

Comment: setAlpha(1) just uses the layout as it is. So it takes very little processing power. set(0.3) means that after the layout is created its opacity is changed in run time.

Comment: In term of processing, both code taking same processing time I have just gone through the setAlpa source code,

Comment: Then i think i am mistaken. Thnaks for the Info. DO you have any images in your layout. Have you checked how set alpha works on images?